# Attempting to deploy a binary to a location where a different binary is already stored

Tags: tridion, tridion2009, tridion-content-delivery

When I am publishing my page from tridio 2009, I am getting the error below:

```
Destination with name 'FTP=[Host=servername, Location=\RET, Password=******, Port=21, UserName=retftp]' reported the following failure:
A processing error occurred processing a transport package Attempting to deploy a binary [Binary id=tcm:553-974947-16 variantId= sg= path=/Images/image_thumbnail01.jpg] to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: tcd:pub[553]/binarymeta[974950]
```

Below is my code snippet

```
Component bigImageComp = th.GetComponentValue("bigimage", imageMetaFields);
string bigImagefileName = string.Empty;
string bigImagePath = string.Empty;
bigImagefileName = bigImageComp.BinaryContent.Filename;
bigImagePath = m_Engine.AddBinary(bigImageComp.Id, TcmUri.UriNull, null, bigImageComp.BinaryContent.GetByteArray(), Path.GetFileName(bigImagefileName));
imageBigNode.InnerText = bigImagePath;
```

Please suggest

Comment: Components tcm:553-974950 and tcm:553-974947 have the same filename, and are being published to the same folder. Rename one of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding binaries you must ensure that the file and it's metadata is unique. If one of the values e.g. the filename appears to be the same but the rest of the metadata does not match, then deployment will fail.

In the given example (as Nuno points out) the binary 910 is trying to deploy over binary 703. The filename is the same but the binary is identified to be not the same (in the case a different ID from the same publication). For this example you will need to rename one of the binaries (either the file itself or change the path) and everything will be fine.

Other scenarios can be that the same image is used from two different templates and the template id is used as the varient ID. If this is the case it is the same image BUT the varient ID check fails so to avoid overwriting the same image the deployer fails it.

Often unpublishing can help, however, the image is only removed when ALL references to it are removed. So if it is used from more than one place there are more open references.

This is logical protection from the deployer. You would not want the wrong image replacing another and either upsetting the layout or potentially changing the content to another meeting (think advertising banner).

This is actual cause and reason for above problem (Something got from forum)

Answer (score 3):

Chris Summers addressed this on his blog. Have a read of the article - http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Generally in Tridion Content Delivery we can only keep one version of a Component. To get multiple "versions" of a MMC we have to publish MMC as variants. By this way we can produce as many variants as we need via templating.

You can refer below article for more  detail:

http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/publishing-images-as-variants.html#!/2012/03/publishing-images-as-variants.html